# Дайте подсказку, как лучше отрефакторить код

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Имеется несколько похожих классов. InterfaceService содержит 1 метод - GetById. IMock - содержит метод GetData, который возвращает IEnumerable. Возможно в дальнейшем будут еще методы добавляться. Подскажите, как лучше отрефакторить повторяющийся код. Думал создать абстрактный класс, но проблема в том, что в одном случае имеется FirstOrDefault, а в другом Where (поменять нельзя, так как в одном случает нужно одно данное, а в другом несколько).

```
public class classService : InterfaceService<T>
{
     private IMock<T> _mockdata;
     public classService(IMock<T> mockData)
     {
         _mockData = mockData;
     }
     public Task<T> GetById(string id)
     {
         return Task.FromResult(_mockData.GetData().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 
         id)//или Where(x => x.Id == id);
     }
}

abstract class MockServiceBase <T> : IMock<T>
   { 
        private IMock<T> _mockData; 
        public MockServiceBase(IMock<T> mockData) 
        { 
           _mockData = mockData; 
        } 
        public IEnumerable<T>GetData() 
        { 
             return _mockData.GetData(); 
        } 
        public abstract void Method () 
        { 
          //здесь думал как добавить метод where или firstordefault 
        } 
        public Task<T> GetById(string id) 
        { 
             return Task.FromResult();//тут тоже не знаю как сделать 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: По-моему, у вас [Ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/184217) - вы описываете свои способы решения проблемы, не описав саму проблему.

Comment: На мой взгляд, у вас должно быть два метода: `Task<T> GetItemById` и `Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetListById`.